# Why do we write pgd address to TTBR0/TTBR1 during each context switch?

Tags: linux-kernel, arm

In the Linux kernel code, why it is required to write pgd(mm_struct->pgd_t) address during every context switch?

Is pgd unique to every process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each process has its own virtual memory space thus there is a single global entry (PGD, Page Global Directory) per process to start mapping from. From PGD, you go to PMD, PTE and finally offset, this helps with sparsity of the mappings (you don't need to have a linear mapping).

See more at [Understanding the Linux Virtual Memory Manager, Chapter 3](https://www.kernel.org/doc/gorman/html/understand/understand006.html)